# How do you take in key inputs without a text field in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

I want to know how to be able to change a JLabel in java Swing to the button I press but I don't know what I'm missing something.  Please help.

What it should end up looking like is on the top of the screen it will show the key being pressed and will update the JLabel as you press it.  Don't worry about the Imports, I have them all in the actual code. Thanks :)

```
public class RandomFrame extends JFrame{
    Dimension Size = new Dimension(800,800);
    ListenForKeys LFK = new ListenForKeys();
    JLabel JInput = new JLabel("");
    JPanel P1 = new JPanel();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RandomFrame();
    }

    public RandomFrame() {
        super("RandomFrame");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(Size);
        P1.add(JInput);
        this.add(P1);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ListenForKeys implements KeyListener {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            String Key = String.valueOf(e.getKeyChar());
            JInput.setText(Key);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get a error when you try to compile your code

Comment: It doesn't look like you are adding the key listener (LFK) to anything. So, you are creating a KeyListener, but it is not assigned to anything so that it can respond to key events. Try adding it either the JFrame (`this.addKeyListener(LFK)`), or the JPanel (`P1.addKeyListener(LFK)`).

Comment: Thank you, P1.addKeyListener(LFK) didn't work but this.addKeyListener(LFK) worked just as I wanted it to.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Austin pointed out that LFK wasn't attached to anything and sure enough, I added it to the JFrame using the line this.addKeyListener(LFK) and sure enough it worked.  Thank you :)